# Google webmaster tools reports "Network Unreachable" for robots.txt, sitemap.xml, and all pages in the sitemap

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

webmaster tools for my site displays that

> robots.txt unreachable

and for all links in sitemap it says

> network unreachable.
> sitemap.xml unreachable.

These appear in crawl stats page.

I discussed with the support team of my hosting and they said...

> Hi,
>
> I have verified apache logs, i cannot
> see any issues on your
> website/webserver/
>
> Possible issues.
>
> 1. There may the routing issue from the googles server to our server.
> 2. When a google bots hits goes high the IP will be automatically
>    blacklisted by our firewall to avoid
>    server loads & downtimes.
>
> As we donot have access to their
> services, We cannot able to give
> details of their details/logs etc.

The sitemaps link shows an exclamation mark which means the file was not reachable.

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you reach your robots.txt or sitemap through your browser?

Comment: Yes. i can read using my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try crawl your site using a fake user agent ID matching Googlebot. (e.g. A1 Website Analyzer allows you change user agent ID)

Some website/webserver "protection" systems also test on if e.g. robots.txt get requested, simultaneous connections etc. You can try run some tests to see how agressive your (if any) protection system its.

However, if your server admin himself states they have an anti bot system then... likely that is the reason.

for future you could try add crawl-delay to robots.txt

Comment: Ok. i will test and i will delay the crawl rate. and will get back here.

Comment: Yes, the hosting has blocked ip which ping very often. i contacted them and they said this. also they requested if it is possible to get the ip of google so that they can unblock

Comment: Your webhost could lookup IPs to see if Googlebot:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-to-verify-googlebot.html