# How to resolve my webmaster crawl issue? URLs unreachable

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

**Issue:** When we tested a sample of the URLs from your Sitemap, we found that some of the URLs were unreachable. Please check your web server for possible misconfiguration, as these errors may be caused by a server error (such as a 5xx error) or a network error between Googlebot and your server. All reachable URLs will still be submitted.

[image]

**Another issue:**

Google couldn't crawl your site because we were unable to access your site's robots.txt file.

[image]

Comment: Sound similar to the "network unreachable" error from Google that was reported here: [Fetch as Google says my page is “Temporary Unreachable”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8901/webmaster-tools-network-unreachable)